# Read more button dont work with <br> element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code below that consist of a `HTML Tab` I have printed out multiple `DOM` Elements inside the tab with a `Read More Button` the function works fine when its just a paragraph but when i add 
 tags inside the paragraph the button doesn't appear anymore does anyone know why this is happening any suggestion / help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

The issue can be seen in the first description of John Doe which has some `<br>` in the text

```js
var personArr = [];
var person = {["first-Name"]:"John", ["last-Name"]:"Doe", ["age"]:21, ["person-desc"]:"<br />Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky <br />boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim <br />sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket.Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin<br /> picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong <br /> ham hock tenderloin shank brisket.<br />"};
var person2 = {["first-Name"]:"Paul", ["last-Name"]:"Logan", ["age"]:22, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket.Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket."};
var person3 = {["first-Name"]:"Sean", ["last-Name"]:"Kim", ["age"]:32, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket.Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket."};
var person4 = {["first-Name"]:"Ken", ["last-Name"]:"Chow", ["age"]:12, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket.Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket."};

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

personArr.forEach((person,i) => {
   var name = document.createElement('h4');
   var desc = document.createElement('p');
   var button = document.createElement('div');

   desc.className = "more";
   name.innerHTML = ` ${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`;
   desc.innerHTML = ` ${person['person-desc']}`;
   frag.appendChild(name);
   frag.appendChild(desc);

});
parent.appendChild(frag);
//<---------------------------------------------- READ MORE FUNCTION ------------------------------------------------------->
$(document).ready(function() {
 var showChar = 300;
 var ellipsestext = "...";
 var moretext = "Read More";
 var lesstext = "Read Less";
 $('.more').each(function() {
  var content = $(this).html();

  if(content.length > showChar) {
   var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
   var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);
   var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink" style="font-size:15px">'+moretext+'</a></span>';
   $(this).html(html);
  }
 });
 $(".morelink").click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
   $(this).removeClass("less");
   $(this).html(moretext);
  } else {
   $(this).addClass("less");
   $(this).html(lesstext);
  }
  $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
  $(this).prev().toggle();
  return false;
 });
});
//<---------------------------------------------- READ MORE FUNCTION ------------------------------------------------------->


//<---------------------------------------------- TAB FUNCTION ------------------------------------------------------->
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
//<---------------------------------------------- TAB FUNCTION ------------------------------------------------------->
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
.line1{
display:inline-block;
}
.size{
width:50%;
}
a.morelink {
 text-decoration:none;
 outline: none;
}
.morecontent span {
 display: none;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class ="size">
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'People')" id="defaultOpen">People</button>
</div>

<div id="People" class="tabcontent">
<div class="line1"> 

 </div>
 </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which tag you attach inside `p` tag

Comment: @Dr.Strange what do you mean?

Comment: which tag not working in `<p>` tag

Comment: @Dr.Strange inside my first array `person` under the `person-desc` there is <br/> tags inside

Comment: so its work properly new line given on first line of paragraph

Comment: Seems you're sub-stringing right in the middle of some HTML elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your substring cuts on `<br`:

```
<br</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink" style="font-size:15px">Read More</a></span>
```

In this case you can save by not chopping the last char, which is wrong anyway - as you can see on the other persons, the last full stop is missing

```
var c = content.substr(0, showChar); // showChar is NOT included
var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar); // so include it here
```

But you really need to check the chopping is not ON a BR

I also translated your DOM to jQuery - I may have broken something in the tab handling - I added a data attribute

```js
var personArr = [];
var person = {
  ["first-Name"]: "John",
  ["last-Name"]: "Doe",
  ["age"]: 21,
  ["person-desc"]: "<br />Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky <br />boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim <br />sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket.Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin<br /> picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong <br /> ham hock tenderloin shank brisket.<br />"
};
var person2 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Paul",
  ["last-Name"]: "Logan",
  ["age"]: 22,
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket.Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket."
};
var person3 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Sean",
  ["last-Name"]: "Kim",
  ["age"]: 32,
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket.Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket."
};
var person4 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Ken",
  ["last-Name"]: "Chow",
  ["age"]: 12,
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket.Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket."
};

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);

var $parent = $('.line1').eq(0);

personArr.forEach((person, i) => {
  var $name = $('<h4/>');
  var $desc = $('<p/>');
  var $button = ('<div/>');

  $desc.addClass("more");
  $name.html(` ${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`);
  $desc.html(` ${person['person-desc']}`);
  $parent.append($name).append($desc);

});

//<---------------------------------------------- READ MORE FUNCTION ------------------------------------------------------->
$(document).ready(function() {
  var showChar = 300;
  var ellipsestext = "...";
  var moretext = "Read More";
  var lesstext = "Read Less";
  $('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if (content.length > showChar) {
      var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
      var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
      
      var lastH = h.lastIndexOf("<");
      if (lastH > h.length-3) {
        // process the tag in however way you need
      }
      
      var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">' + ellipsestext + '</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink" style="font-size:15px">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
      console.log(c, html)

      $(this).html(html);
    }
  });
  $(".morelink").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
      $(this).removeClass("less");
      $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("less");
      $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
//<---------------------------------------------- READ MORE FUNCTION ------------------------------------------------------->


//<---------------------------------------------- TAB FUNCTION ------------------------------------------------------->
$(".tablinks").on("click",function() {
  var cityName = $(this).attr("data-id");
  $(".tabcontent").hide()
  $(".tablinks").removeClass("active");
  $("#"+cityName).show();
  $(this).addClass("active");
})
$("#defaultOpen").click(); 
//<---------------------------------------------- TAB FUNCTION ------------------------------------------------------->
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.line1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.size {
  width: 50%;
}

a.morelink {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.morecontent span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="size">
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" id="defaultOpen" data-id="People">People</button>
    </div>

    <div id="People" class="tabcontent">
      <div class="line1">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```